# How to call an angular function within another function?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

I have three select options in my html page. Based on the three selecting values I need to write a value in another text box.

```
  <select (change)="aaFilter($event.target.value)" class="form-control">
        <option *ngFor="let type of aa" [value]="type.value"> 
         {{type.display}}
        </option>
    </select>

  <select (change)="bbFilter($event.target.value)" class="form-control">
        <option *ngFor="let type of bb" [value]="type.value"> 
         {{type.display}}
        </option>
    </select>

   <select (change)="ccFilter($event.target.value)" class="form-control">
        <option *ngFor="let type of cc" [value]="type.value"> 
         {{type.display}}
        </option>
    </select>


So I have Onchange function in every select box. Now In my typescript file my 

 aaFilter(selectedaa:string){
    console.log('value is ',selectedaa);
 }
```

Likewise I have written three functions. But based on this values I need to set up a value in textbox.

```
   headerName(){

      //Here I need to take up the threee selected values from drop down & do some function based on that. 
   }
```

How can that be done in angular 6 & typescript?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do... Can't you just call `this.headerName()` from inside your `aaFilter`, `bbFilter` and `ccFilter` functions?

Answer (score 0):

In component:

```
Public selectedValues = [];

aaFilter(value, index){
this.selectedValues[index] = value;
this.updateModelInput();
}

bbFilter(value, index){
this.selectedValues[index] = value;
this.updateModelInput();
}

ccFilter(value, index){
this.selectedValues[index] = value;
this.updateModelInput();
}

updateModelInput(){
   if(this.selectedValues.length === 3){
       // UPDATE THE VALUE IN TEXT BOX
   }
}
```

From Template, you can pass value 0, 1, 2 as 2nd parameter in change method.

Comment: This list of `selectedValues` will never stop growing. Each time any one of the selects is changed, it pushes a new value into the array

Answer (score 0):

Well, you haven't bound anything to the select options have you?

```
  <select 
       [(ngModel)] ="filterA"
       (change)    ="headerName()" 
        class      ="form-control">
      <option *ngFor="let type of aa" [value]="type.value"> 
         {{type.display}}
      </option>
  </select>

  <select            
       [(ngModel)] ="filterB"
       (change)    ="headerName()" 
        class      ="form-control">
      <option *ngFor ="let type of bb" [value]="type.value"> 
         {{type.display}}
      </option>
  </select>

  <select            
       [(ngModel)] ="filterC"
       (change)    ="headerName()" 
        class      ="form-control">
      <option *ngFor="let type of cc" [value]="type.value"> 
        {{type.display}}
      </option>
  </select>
```

In your component file:

```
headerName()
{
    /* Do whatever this function is supposed to do whenever one of the 
       filters is changed. The variables filterA, filterB and filterC will 
       now always have the most recent values for you to operate on */
}
```